# page size and font size in latex beamer

Tags: beamer, fontsize, pdfpages

I need to add page size as `Letter Paper: 8-1/2X11` and font size `24 pt` but the following code does not worked. What is a solution for these two changes?

```
\documentclass[24pt]{beamer}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `beamerposter` package to set a custom page size:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=custom,width=21.59,height=27.94]{beamerposter}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{slide title}
this is written in 24 point font.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Notice that the height and width are in cm-- beamerposter seems to require that.  And the line `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` removes the navigation symbols from the bottom of the page.  You can remove that line if you want to keep them.

Comment: I used it.Did some changes,bcz i need horizontal format.But 24pt not worked.not changed the font size..what is a reason for it?My code is,                                                \documentclass[24pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=Landscape,size=custom,width=27.5,height=21.25]{beamerposter}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{aaaa}
bbmbnmnbnmbmbm
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Comment: I used \begin{spacing}{1.5} and \end{spacing},before it worked.But after adding \usepackage[orientation=Landscape,size=custom,width=27.5,height=21.25]{beamerpos‌​ter} didn't work spacing and words become too small...what is a solution for that?thank u

Comment: The 24pt works perfectly for me, but I think it's one of the newer size options. Do you have the latest version of `beamer`?

Comment: I used miktex-2.8.3761 .but font size is not working as \documentclass[24pt]{beamer} .

Comment: Interestingly, it seems to default to 24pt for me-- removing the [24pt] didn't have an effect, and when I printed out the same text from the result, and a comparison document in Word with 24 point text, the size was exactly the same.

Comment: `beamerposter` does accept a "scale" option, that adjusts the size of fonts.  You can try adjusting that to get exactly a 24 point font.  It would probably take some trial and error to get the correct scale factor.